# Haskell: Divide Integer by Integer and get Double

Tags: haskell, division

I want to write a Haskell function which takes two `Integer`s divedes them and outputs a `Double`.

The signature should look like this:

```
divide :: Integer -> Integer -> Double
```

The function I would like to have is:

```
divide x y = x / y
```

The error message I get wit this function is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Integer’
```

How to get a correct double result for this function?

Comment: what type does `(/)` have?

Comment: `fromInteger` is your friend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haskell is a *strongly* typed language. That means that *no* implicit conversions re done. You can first convert the two numbers to a `Double`, for example with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral), and then use [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-):

```
divide :: Integer -> Integer -> Double
divide x y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y
```

Convertin a number to a `Double` can result in loss of precision however.

It might be better to return a [**`Ratio`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#t:Ratio), and thus use *fractions*, for example with the [**`(%) :: Integral i => i -> i -> Ratio i`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-), so then `divide` is just `divide = (%)`.

You can, like [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762352/haskell-divide-integer-by-integer-and-get-double/60762460?noredirect=1#comment107505786_60762460) use `fromRational` to covert the `Rational` to any `Fractional` type:

```
import Data.Ratio((%))

divide :: Fractional a => Integer -> Integer -> a
divide x y = fromRational (x % y)
```

So then you can still convert it to a `Double`:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> divide 5 2 :: Double
2.5
```

Comment: You can get the good behavior of `%` (namely, dealing correctly with numbers too large to fit in a `Double` but whose ratio is small enough or vice versa) and the "good" type of `divide` by combining the two: `divide' :: Integer -> Integer -> Double; divide' x y = fromRational (x % y)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The signature is given from an example I need to do for university.